# Outputting long string to file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I feel like this is a pretty easy problem and was wondering if there is a clean solution I was unaware of. I basically have some output and i want to nest it into an html file that I generate. The html file has static headings so I was just going to make that html code into a string and output the header first, then the data.

The problem is that the header is somewhat long, and I would have to remove allll the spacing to place it into a string without errors. Is there a simple way to do this I'm not seeing?

Example:

```
ofstream write;
write.open("myHTML.html");
//errors below because there is spacing in the string
string header = "<html>
                 <HEAD><TITLE>Shortest path from Panama to Guatemala</TITLE></HEAD>
                 etc... alot more heading stuff";
write << header;
//data is written after this
```

The only solution I can think of is having the heading in another file, read all of that into a string, then writing it back into the html file before I add the output

Comment: You can do `"abc" "def"` to get a single `"abcdef"` while bypassing string literal length limits. You might also be interested in raw string literals if storing that type of data into a string.

Comment: What error are you getting from the long string? Strings should be able to hold millions of characters.

Comment: It's not so much the length that is the problem but the fact that I have new lines in the string. I could just remove all the new lines so the html code isn't formatted but I was hoping there was another way. I'll try your way Chris

Comment: Is this what you want to do? http://ideone.com/CgypbS

Comment: That works great actually, didn't know I could concatenate like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put multiple quote enclosed strings one after another.  The compiler will concatenate them for you.

```
string header = "<html>"
                "<HEAD><TITLE>Shortest path from Panama to Guatemala</TITLE></HEAD>"
                "etc... alot more heading stuff";
```

If you want newline characters in there, then embed them into the string.

```
string header = "<html>\n"
                "<HEAD><TITLE>Shortest path from Panama to Guatemala</TITLE></HEAD>\n"
                "etc... alot more heading stuff\n";
```

Comment: ah, never knew I could concatenate like that. Fantastic, thank you

Comment: Of course raw string literals take literal newlines into account, so you don't even need to embed newlines, just physically put the next line on the next line.

Comment: @chris: Yeah, but then you have to choose either ugly output, or ugly source code. http://liveworkspace.org/code/xYpV7$14

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I know the feeling. I keep my raw literals left-aligned and start the literals themselves on new lines.